# How to prevent a user from using ctrl-c to stop a script?

Tags: bash, shell

I load a script in `.bash_profile` and this script will ask for right password whenever a user opens a terminal window. If the user enters a wrong code, the script will run `exit` to stop the current terminal.

```
if [ $code = "980425" ]; then
    echo hello
else
    exit
fi
```

But I realize that the user can always use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> 
to stop the script and enter the terminal. 
How to avoid that?

Comment: You'll need to hook into the raw TTY  stream, (not "canonical")

Comment: @argon That'll just move SIGINT to a different key. There's not need to mess with tty settings; the trap shell-builtin can install a handler or ignore SIGINT just fine.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `.bash_profile` for authentication if you're trying to genuinely secure a system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always trap `SIGINT`:

```
trap 'echo got SIGINT' SIGINT
```

Once you're done, reinstall the default handler again with

```
trap SIGINT
```

See the [POSIX spec for trap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) for details. This works in all Bourne shells, not just bash.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
trap '' 2 
commands
trap 2
```

This disables signal 2 (control c) and then re-enables it after the command has run.