# Problem with trapping SIGINT using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I'd like to block CTRL-C but it doesn't work as expected.
I was following the answer described [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37148777/12512199) but without success.

I must be missing something but can't figure out what. It's as if CTRL-C is intercepted but still propagated:

First I ran the following script and hit CTRL-C; the message is displayed but the script exited.

```sh
echo  "
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "Ctrl + C happened"' SIGINT

sleep infinity
" > test.sh
chmod +x test.sh
./test.sh
```

Then I checked if it would behave differently in a container as pid 1:

```sh
echo  "
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "Ctrl + C happened"' SIGINT

sleep infinity
" > test.sh
chmod +x test.sh
docker rm -f conttest
docker container create --name conttest -it --entrypoint="bash" ubuntu:20.04 -x -c /test.sh
docker cp test.sh conttest:/test.sh
docker container start --attach -i conttest
```

But no, it's the same behavior.
I ran those tests on Unbuntu 20.04.
Read https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap but still haven't found any clue ...
Any idea?

Comment: After publishing the question, it hits me : it must be because after processing the signal INT, we never go back running `sleep infinity`...
Is there a nice way to keep running the interrupted command ?

Comment: As you're running the container, there's an unnecessary `bash -x -c` wrapper and your script may not be pid 1.  Does it behave differently if you `docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD:/test" ubuntu:20.04 /test/test.sh`?

Comment: @DavidMaze
Arguments destined to bash seemed to be processed as expected and bash is the process of pid 1


```bash
root@f054dc4b0a82:/# ps -edf --forest
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           7       0  0 09:04 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root          15       7  0 09:04 pts/1    00:00:00  \_ ps -edf --forest
root           1       0  0 09:04 pts/0    00:00:00 bash -v -x -c /test.sh
root           6       1  0 09:04 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep infinity
root@f054dc4b0a82:/# 
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control+C or any other key combination mapped to *intr* in output of
`stty -a` sends SIGINT to all processes in the foreground. Shell
receives it but so does `sleep infinity` which dies and shell exits
because it has nothing to do. If you want your script it to run
continuously and do something on SIGINT you have to use an endless
loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Ctrl + C happened"' SIGINT

while true
do
    sleep infinity
done
```

If you only want to ignore SIGINT:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap '' SIGINT

sleep infinity
```

Comment: So there is a way to prevent CTRL-C from acting. Missed that. Thanks. Any suggestion for further reading either for signals in shell or stty ?